# load a jsp in a dialog and div

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I know this might be a duplication question, but I couldn't find the answer for this simple question. I want to load a new jsp file in a dialog and a div.

```
Structure:
 -WebContent
   -jsp
     -viewfolder
       -helloworld.jsp
       -helloworldedit.jsp
       -newworld.jsp
```

let's say I have `helloworld.jsp` which is loaded from request dispatcher. I want to load `newworld.jsp` in a div tag in `helloworld.jsp`.

```
<div id="result"></div>

$('#result').load('/jsp/viewfolder/newworld.jsp');
```

Tried the above code, didn't work.

I have also tried to load a jsp page into a dialog and this one has failed too.

```
<button id="button">button</button>
<div id="dialog"></div>

$('#button').on("click", function() {
        $('#dialog').load('/jsp/viewfolder/helloworldedit.jsp').dialog();
    });
```

The question I have is, this is the right way to call the jsp page or do I have to load the page from request dispatcher using ajax.

To test if the path is correct, I tried to put a `calendar.gif` in the same folder and I was able to reach it from the context.

```
http://localhost:port/.projectcontext/jsp/viewfolder/calendar.gif.
```

Comment: Note that in your code above, you're trying to select `result` elements rather than the element with id="result".  Is there any reason why you couldn't just use server side includes?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for `DOM ready` event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').on("click", function() {
        $('#dialog').load('/.projectcontext/jsp/viewfolder/helloworldedit.jsp').dialog();
    });
});
```

Comment: Any errors? If your JS is in the JSP page, is it enclosed in `script` tags?

Comment: What is the absolute `URL` of the `jsp` page you're trying to load?

Comment: `http://localhost:port/.projectcontext/jsp/viewfolder/helloworldedit.jsp` This should be absolute URL. But I can't open the jsp page

Comment: Then you want to use the `URL` `/.projectcontext/jsp/viewfolder/helloworldedit.jsp` or the absolute URL or if this page is in the same folder as the one loading it use, `helloworldedit.jsp`.

Comment: I also tried `{request.contextPath}/jsp/viewfolder/helloworldedit.jsp`. this didn't work either. All I get is `500 Internal Server Error` And also `helloworldedit.jsp` which didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

*Try below code :-*

Suppose you have a `div` in `newworld.jsp` which contains all data which you want to load in another `div` which is present in `helloworld.jsp`

**newworld.jsp**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="target">
            <!-- other HTML controls -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**helloworld.jsp**

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadPage();">Click Me</a>
<div id="page"></div>

<script>
    function loadPage(){
        $('#page').load('newworld.jsp #target');

        or
        // If you choose this method then give path of JSP to be loaded in
        // anchor tag
        $('#page').load($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

**OR**

You can use **JSP include tag** like this

```
<div id="page" style="width:300px; height:300px;">  
    <jsp:include page="path of the page to be loaded"></jsp:include>  
</div>
```