# load a local jsp file containing html in a div block of another jsp file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring, jsp

i have multiple jsp files(contains html) in webapp/views of my application and i want to do something like this in one jsp file

```
$("#my_div_id).append("my_file2.jsp")
```

**requirement** :
 i want to inject a particular html content which i stored as jsp in a div block of other jsp file through jquery.

tried :
 $(#id).load("file2.jsp") and its not working and came to know it makes ajax call and fetches remote content only

thought of another approach by keeping my html content in `<script type = "html">` of first jsp file itself but unable to figure out how to push that html in script tag to required div element

saw other answers [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script) [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330195/load-a-jsp-in-a-dialog-and-div) but unable solve my requirement

Comment: `$("#id").load("file2.jsp")` should work if on same origin. Look in the console and network tab